# C# + SQL Server ExecuteScalar() not returning last inserted id

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following function that executes an query and returns true on success and false on failure. No I wanted to extend the method so that with every insert query that is fired, the class var `insertId` contains the ID of the last inserted row.

The problem is that `insertId` is always 0, so somehow the `executeScalar()` is not returning the ID.

Any ideas? Or other solutions to get the ID of the last insert query....

```
    public int insertId;        

    public bool executeCommand(string q) {
        q += "; SELECT @@IDENTITY AS LastID";
        bool retour = true;
        SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(Settings.DSN);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, myCon);
        try {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            insertId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (insertId > 0) {
                MessageBox.Show(insertId.ToString());
            }

            myCon.Close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            this.error = ex.Message;
            retour = false;
        }
        return retour;
    }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should change your `INSERT` to return that inserted ID to you right away (in an `OUTPUT` clause)! This works from SQL Server 2005 on - the `OUTPUT` clause isn't available in SQL Server 2000 or earlier (you didn't specify which **version** of SQL Server you're using in your question...). Read more about the [`OUTPUT` clause on MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

Change your insert to be something like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)   
OUTPUT Inserted.ID
VALUES(Val1, Val2, ..., ValN);
```

and then when you execute your insert statement from C#, you should be able to do:

```
using(SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand("INSERT.....", myCon))
{
   myCon.Open();
   var result = cmdInsert.ExecuteScalar();
   myCon.Close();
}
```

and your `result` variable should now contain the proper, freshly inserted value!

Comment: I'm using the 2005 version... I'm going to try this but it's going to be some work because all the insert queries are already written... EDIT : Thank you! This worked, the result now contains the id of the inserted row

Comment: Thanks a lot. But remember that Inserted.ID means Inserted.name of ID column :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona de maravilla :D

Answer (score 2):

Try SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY, if that doesn't work can you post the table schema and the insert query you are running.