# Inserting Row and getting Id, get error

Tags: c#, insert, sql-server-ce, identity

I insert a value / new row and I need the ID, but I get an error...

SQL code:

```
INSERT INTO [StoneTable] ([StoneName]) VALUES (@StoneName)
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Using this code to insert row and getting the ID:

```
stoneTableTableAdapter = new StoneTableTabelleTableAdapter();
int id = Convert.ToInt32(stoneTableTableAdapter.InsertStoneNameAndReturnId("anything"));
//And on this 2nd Line I got an error
```

Error message:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = SELECT ]

What's the problem? In my other project I use the same syntax, with no problems. Tried with `@@IDENTITY`, as well not working....

Comment: Which SQL database system are you using? MySQL? MSSQL? PostgreSQL?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5

Comment: What is the output of `stoneTableTableAdapter.Insert...("anything")` call?  It looks like it's not the `int` you thought it'd be.  Debug and see what that method is returning in reality.

Comment: @Shark He stops at this line and gives me the Errormessage and it is int

Comment: Try adding a semi-colon to the end of the insert and giving a name to your select variable, SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ReturnValue.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136536/possible-to-retrieve-identity-column-value-on-insert-using-sqlcommandbuilder-wi - seems to talk about the same problem (and offers some solutions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375231/c-sharp-sql-server-executescalar-not-returning-last-inserted-id) for a suggestion on how to make your example work:

> You should change your INSERT to return that inserted ID to you right away (in an OUTPUT clause)

Answer (score 0):

You can only issue a single statement per batch in SQL Server Compact, and you cannot use Scope_identity, but must use @@IDENTITY (remember to keep the connection open betweeen the two calls)