# How to get the inserted row autoincrement id?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

In [C# + SQL Server ExecuteScalar() not returning last inserted id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375231/c-sharp-sql-server-executescalar-not-returning-last-inserted-id) I found a nice solution to get the inserted row autoincrement id. So now my query looks just like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)   
OUTPUT Inserted.ID
VALUES(Val1, Val2, ..., ValN);
```

But unfortunately I am on SQL Server 2000 and this syntax is not available.

What can I use there to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @@IDENTITY in Sql Server 2000

However you need to be aware of the limitations (which were overcome by SCOPE_IDENTITY). See this article for an explanation  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

EDIT

MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259185%28v=sql.80%29.aspx says that SCOPE_IDENTITY **is** avaiable in SS2000, so I recomment that you use it instead.

You can get the value by executing `SET @<var> = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

This link http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/Getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record has some more examples of how to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`

Comment: And how should I return it from the query?

Answer (score 0):

The answer I have working is to insert rows through a stored procedure, as `OUTPUT` keyword is not available in ms sql server 2000. Also I had to abandon `inserted` by the same reason and used `scope_identity`.

Well, it looks somewhat like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertRow]      
    @pDate datetime,
    @pId int OUTPUT
AS  
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO nl$RegisterRace ([Date],...)
    VALUES (@pDate,...);

    SET @pId = scope_identity();
END
```

Comment: You can also use RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY() to return the ID if you don't want to use an OUTPUT parameter.